# Input will not focus (HTML)

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, setfocus

Before you report as duplicate, please note that I have been looking for answers for the last 2 weeks, and Chrome will still not focus on an `input`.

I am making a web-terminal type page, and so I direct all key input into an `input` element. I made the `input` have an opacity of `0.01` and be 1x1 pixels and copy the value of the input into a `span` element because I wanted a little cursor to follow the text written into the prompt, and I did not want to constantly resize the input.

I have tried umpteen amounts of ways to focus into the `input` element, and I found that even if i have it with `100%` opacity and 100x10 pixels, when I click it like you conventially would to type in to a text field, it would not focus.

The input HTML:

```
<input type="text" autofocus class="invisible in" type="text" autocomplete="off">
```

The Input CSS:

```
.in, .invisible {
    opacity: 1;
    background: #000000 !important;
    height: 1px;
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1px;
    outline: none;
}
```

The Focus JS:

```
$('#chrome').click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.in').focus();
    }, 100);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#chrome-input').click();
        $('.in').focus();
    }, 1000);
    window.onkeydown = function() {
        document.getElementsByClassName('in')[0].focus()
    }    
});
```

As you can see, I have tried many different ways of focusing on my `input`, but none of them work.

PS: Please do not scrutinize my large list of bad habits I have developed from self-teaching myself at a young age.

The page is http://stanstrum.comxa.com/project/term

Comment: `height: 1px;`? `font-size: 1px;`? What element is `#chrome`?

Comment: It is working. You just made it so small it is not visible! It is also black background with black text. See it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rrACeVsDokZp7w1zXtpT?p=preview). There could be something wrong with your browser.

Comment: How does this fiddle with your code not have focus on the input?: https://jsfiddle.net/acen69bc/

Comment: It works in JSFiddle but not on my webpage, and I check the input with `setInterval(function(){ console.log($('.in').val()) }, 100)`

Comment: #chrome is a button that onclicked will fire `click` on input attempting to focus `.in` and couldn't focus at all when it was 0px or opacity 0